# Custom setting (Hierarchical) is not working for formula field.

Tags: formula-field, customsetting

I have a Formula field 'Alert' on my CASE object that should display an image (Warning) when 'Year/Model' field on CASE object is equal to 5 particular values (2001/Accord, 2002/Accord, 2001/CIVIC, 2002/CIVIC, 2003/PILOT).

I tried using logic in formula field, but an error is displayed - 'Logic is too big to execute'. so trying to use custom settings. I created a custom setting but field in the custom setting is allowing me to store only 1 record, not multiple.

Please suggest an idea when 'Year/Model' field is equal to five particular values, my formula field should display a image.

Please share any idea.

Comment: Use the Case statement in the formula instead of using IF statement

Comment: Thanks for your idea!! There is one more IF condition in my formula field, if i am including any other functions getting same error - 'Too big to execute'..any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Venky -- you'll need to google on tips to reduce formula field size.  CASE is more efficient than multiple IFs; `CONTAINS('xx:yy:zz',comparand)` is also more efficient than multiple IFs. But without seeing the whole formula; it is impossible to diagnose.  Your best bet is to start with small formula (note size), then selectively add to see where things get out of hand